# USB HDD Constantly accessed every 0.25 seconds only when mounted

Tags: usb-drive

So I recently purchased a Seagate 16TB external USB hard drive (STKP16000400), it actually arrived earlier today.

The first thing I did was wipe the disk, create a new GPT partition table with a single partition spanning the full disk, and then encrypted the partition with luks:

`sudo cryptsetup luksFormat --type luks2 /dev/sda1`

I then formatted it as ext4:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 sda_crypt
<<entered password>>
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/sda_crypt
```

At this point, the disk is completely inactive and quiet. If I then mount the disk to a folder, I get about 10-15 seconds of constant activity, then it becomes a rhythmic "ticking" about every quarter second.

To investigate further, I temporarily disabled the uas module for this drive:
(I physically disconnected the USB drive before doing this)

```
sudo rmmod uas
sudo rmmod usb_storage
sudo modprobe usb_storage quirks=0bc2:2038:u
```

This allows me to run smartctl and hdparm commands against the drive.

After reconnecting and mounting the drive again, I tried running `hdparm -y /dev/sda` to suspend the disk, which did temporarily stop the rhythmic ticking for a couple of seconds, but the disk just spins right back up and resumes it's incessant ticking.

Lastly, I checked the S.M.A.R.T. status:

`sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda`

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.5.4-76060504-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST16000NM000J-2TW103
Serial Number:    ZR5EM3Y7
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0e6ba8eed
Firmware Version: SN04
User Capacity:    16,000,900,661,248 bytes [16.0 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-4 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Nov 21 17:25:52 2023 CST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  559) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:           (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:   (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:   (1410) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:   (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:         (0x70bd)  SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   075   067   044    Pre-fail  Always       -       29819295
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   093   093   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       10
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   100   253   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       82746
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       9
 18 Unknown_Attribute       0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   058   057   000    Old_age   Always       -       42 (Min/Max 42/42)
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       11
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   042   043   000    Old_age   Always       -       42 (0 17 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0023   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1 (93 203 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       27972491
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1846804

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

The only thing I really noticed here is that the raw value for Seek_Error_Rate is pretty high, but those raw values tend to be in a manufacturer-specific format, so... who knows.

Anyway, there's nothing on the disk yet, it's just an empty ext4 partition with the default `lost+found` folder and nothing else, so there's no reason it should be constantly accessing the disk while it's mounted. As soon as I `umount` the partition, it stops. Not only is it annoying having it constantly ticking, but it adds a lot of wear and tear doing this.

Is there anything else I can do to figure out why it's doing this, and more importantly, get it to stop?